# How do I convert my tuple into the format so that it is acceptable for the JSON format in Python

Tags: python, angular, flask-restful

I currently have this method in python code  :

```
@app.route('/getData', methods = ['GET'])
def get_Data():

    c.execute("SELECT abstract,category,date,url  from Data")
    data = c.fetchall()   
    resp = jsonify(data)
    resp.status_code = 200
    return resp
```

The output I get from this is:

```
[
  [
    "2020-04-23 15:32:13",
    "Space",
    "https://www.bisnow.com/new-jersey",
    "temp"
  ],
  [
    "2020-04-23 15:32:13",
    "Space",
    "https://www.bisnow.com/events/new-york",
    "temp"
  ]
]
```

However, I want the output to look like this:

```
[
   {
    "abstract": "test", 
    "category": "journal", 
    "date": "12-02-2020", 
    "link": "www.google.com"
   },
   {
    "abstract": "test", 
    "category": "journal", 
    "date": "12-02-2020", 
    "link": "www.google.com"
   }
]
```

How do I convert my output into an expected format?

Comment: Use a *dictionary*?

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe indicates, you simply cannot expect the tuple coming from this database query to turn into a dictionary in the JSON output. Your `data` variable *does not* contain the information necessary to construct the response you desire.

It will depend on your database but my recommendation would be to find a way to retrieve dicts from your database query instead of tuples, in which case the rest of your code should work as is. For instance, for sqlite, you could define your cursor `c` like this:

```py
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('dbname.db') # database connection details here...
connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
c = connection.cursor()
```

Now, if your database for some reason cannot support a dictionary cursor, you need to roll your own dictionary after retrieving the database query results. For your example, something like this:

```py
fieldnames = ('abstract', 'category', 'date', 'link')
numfields = len(fieldnames)
data = []
for row in c.fetchall():
    for idx in range(0, numfields - 1):
        dictrow[fields[idx]] = row[idx]
    data.append(dictrow)
```

I iterate over a list of field labels, which do not have to match your database columns but *do* have to be in the same order, and creating a dict by pairing the label with the datum from the db tuple in the same position. This passage would replace the single line `data = c.fetchall()` in OP.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I am using SQLite database.This is how I am making a connection

conn = None
c = None
conn = sqlite3.connect('crawler.db',check_same_thread=False)
c = conn.cursor()

and I am importing jasonify from flask library to convert it into JSON object

Comment: @KamranArshad in that case, try adding the line `conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row` after your initial `conn = ...` line. That should give you dict rows instead of tuples. I will update my answer.

Comment: @KamranArshad glad to hear it! Would you mind accepting the answer if it worked for you? Thanks!